# Python Pandas delete row where column string has duplicate words included

Tags: pandas, delete-row

I am creating a list of URLs and importing into a pandas dataframe.

I would like to drop any rows where the end of the string contains the word "-program"

https://coned.somecollege.com/courses-and-programs/some-course-program

```
df = df[df["my_url"].str.contains("-program") == False]
```

Using the above instruction deletes all my rows because they all have "/courses-and-programs/" in the URL.

I would like to delete the row only if the last 8 characters are "-program"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) to match the end of string and the boolean NOT (`~`) rather than `== False`:

```
out = df[~df['my_url'].str.endswith('-program')]
```